# How to make the position of an element Directive relative to an ng-repeated item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` list of tag objects from an array. When you hover over any tag, a `<tags-hover>` element related to that tag displays additional tag information.

With the way I have my markup and code setup, the `<tags-hover>` does display the correct information for each tag hovered. However, the position of the `<tags-hover>` that shows up is always the last one in the `ng-repeat` list.

The ideal situation would be that the `<tags-hover>` for each tag hovered, would appear directly below that tag, and not always the last one.

---

UPDATE I'm using a [**scopeFactory**](https://gist.github.com/leongaban/30b1b1bfa830fa5fb961) to save and store scopes for my controllers and directives, looks like I may need a way to index the scope of the `tagHover` I need.

---

[image]
< I'm hovering over the first tag here.

**My markup in the tagsPanel:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags | filter:filterTags | orderBy:predicate:reverse"
        ng-class="{'selected': m.selected}"
        ng-mouseover="hoverTag(m)"
        ng-mouseleave="leaveTag()"
        ng-click="selectTag(m)" class="tag-li" style="transition-delay: {{$index * 60}}ms">

        <div class="tag"
             ng-class="{'positive': m.direction == 'positive',
                        'negative': m.direction == 'negative',
                        ''        : m.direction == 'stagnant'}">
                        {{m.term}} 
        </div>

        <!-- below is that popover div with tag details -->
        <tags-hover></tags-hover>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**tagsHover HTML markup:**

```
<div class="tags-hover-container" ng-show="tagsHoverDisplay">
    ...
```

**tagsHover Styling:**

```
.tags-hover-container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    background: $gray_bg;
    border: 1px solid $gray2;
    z-index: 10000;
    @include rounded(3px);
    @include clearfix;

    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 26px;
        z-index: 9999;
        @include triangle(up, 10px, $gray_bg);
    }

    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: -11px;
        left: 25px;
        z-index: 9998;
        @include triangle(up, 11px, $gray2);
    }
}
```

**tagsPanel Controller:**

```
vs.hoverTag = function(tagObj) {
    tagsHover = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover');
    tagsHover.breakTimeout = true;
    TagDetailsFactory.saveTagDetails(vs.ticker, tagObj);
};

vs.leaveTag = function() {
    tagsHover.breakTimeout = false;
    tagsHover = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover');
    $timeout(tagsHover.leavingTag, 500);
};
```

**The inbetween service tagsDetailsFactory:**

```
var saveTagDetails = function(ticker, tag) {

    ApiFactory.getTagData(ticker, tag.term_id).then(function(data) {

        // API code and data calculation stuffs...

        tag.tweet_percentage = increase;
        details.direction    = tag.direction;
        //etc etc ...

        // I get the scope of the tagsHover Directive and then call hoveringTag()
        tagsHover = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover');
        tagsHover.hoveringTag();
    });
};
```

The code in my tagHover Directive:

```
var vs                  = $scope;
    vs.breakTimeout     = false,
    vs.tagDetails       = {},
    vs.tagsHoverDisplay = false;
    ScopeFactory.saveScope('tagsHover', vs);

vs.hoveringTag = function() {
    vs.tagDetails       = {};
    vs.tagDetails       = TagDetailsFactory.getTagDetails();
    vs.tagsHoverDisplay = true;
};

vs.leavingTag = function() {
    if (vs.breakTimeout) {} else {
        vs.tagsHoverDisplay = false;
    }
};
```

How would you approaching fixing the  that displays is the one relative to the tag that was hovered? And not the last one in the `ng-repeat`?

Note here is a screenshot of the HTML from chrome dev tools, even when I hover over other tags, the tags-hover in the last `li` gets all the updating, I see the `tweets` count change only in that last one:

[image]

Comment: It looks more like css problem than a angular problem. Can you add the css related to the list and tags-hover-container?

Comment: @mrak Styling added! If the tag-hover that showed up was directly below the tag the user hovered over, this styling would work fine I believe. It's just that it's the last one that shows up. There are many `<tag-hover>` on the page due to the `ng-repeat`, could that be an issue in anyway?

Comment: Try removing `float:left` and `@include clearfix`. Either (or both) of those could cause behaviour like this.

Comment: I don't believe that the number of the `<tag-hover>` is the problem. You can inspect the live changes on the html with dev tools, maybe this will bring some clarity?

Comment: @HankScorpio tried that, broke the styling, position still the same :( @mark yup I checked the dev tools and only the last `<tag-hover>` is getting any of the updated data, posting a screenshot. Also adding additional code...

Comment: Do you use `ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover')` to access the scope of the currently hovered `<tag-hover>`? I don't know how exactly your ScopeFactory works but in the tag-hover directive you call  `ScopeFactory.saveScope('tagsHover', vs);` So if the ScopeFactory is a key - value store, than only the last scope is saved (all other scopes with the same key are overwritten).

Comment: you use `ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsHover')` quite frequently here in the code, presumably to get the `$scope` object for the `tagsHover` directive.  However, every time the directive gets initialized, it's overwriting the previous value, via `ScopeFactory.saveScope('tagsHover', vs);`.  You'll actually need to find a way to index each scope in an array.

Comment: @Claies ah yeah hmmm... yeah need to think about that, but thanks! That is most likely it.

Comment: @mrak beat me by about 30 seconds, but we are both saying essentially the same thing here.

Comment: How would you guys have handled this without a scopeFactory service? I had thought about using `broadcast`, but worried it would be too hard to destroy all the events when I don't need them.

Comment: @Claies my lucky day :-) My suggestion: 1) Not to use anything to access the scope of other elements. I think this will mess up your code... 2) Use your tag item as model for the hoverTag directive. Than in hoverTag(m) you can set `m.tagsHoverDisplay = true` to display the tag. I'm trying to make a example in plunkr...

Comment: I think I agree... `ScopeFactory` tends to be just another form of a global dumping ground; it's not really any better than passing variables across `$rootScope`.  The right approach is for the directive to have an isolate scope and have the parameters supplied.

Comment: @Claies thanks! I've heard of isolate scope a lot, guess it's time to dig in and figure them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already shown in the comments, the most probably reason that only one `<tags-hover>` is visible is the ScopeFactory.

My solution is to keep the decision if a `<tags-hover>` is visible in the model and avoid accessing scopes of other elements.

Code example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aHUh1AX7hMyafzaCZnPI?p=preview

```
.directive('tagDetails', function() {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
      console.debug($scope, attrs);
    },
    scope:{
        tag:'=ngModel'
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="tag.showDetails">{{tag.details}}</div>'
  };
})
```

I implemented the directive in this way, that its visibility depends on the `showDetails` property which belongs to the model.

Now all I need is to change this property, e.x. in the controller

```
$scope.showTagDetails = function(t) {
  t.showDetails = true;
}
```

Corresponding html:

```
<li ng-repeat="t in tags">
  <div ng-mouseover="showTagDetails(t)">{{t.name}}</div>
  <tag-details ng-model="t"></tag-details>
</li>
```

The `showDetails` doesn't have to be initialized with false: It will simply evaluate to false if the property is not there.

The only disadvantage is that you need to add this property to your model data and it could eventually overwrite something else.
I that case you would need to wrap your model in another object.

Comment: you also would need to implement `hideTagDetails` in a similar fashion, to hide the popover on `ng-mouseleave`.

Comment: Sweet thanks! I should be able to pass `t` along the various controllers, services and finally directive to make this work...

Comment: @Claies you are right. Other way would be to iterate over the tags in `showTagDetails` and reset `showDetails = false`

Comment: also, without using an isolate scope, if you happen to have more than one tag-hover appear at the same time on the page, they will all be identical, the last template generated.  but using an isolate scope can complicate the definition, and may not be necessary if it's not possible for multiple tag-hover elements to show.

Comment: Ok NICE, I'm going to have to refactor a lot of stuff to work this way :D and I was all proud of coming up with `scopeFactory` lol...